# How to use vizceral graph(vizceral.js) for showing data flow in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when i try to imperilment it the graph doesn't show up. How do i achieve this feature?
i am getting the following error in the controller at default:Syntax error on token "default", Identifier expected`var viz = new Vizceral.default(document.getElementById('vizceral'));`

I am using this example Click here https://github.com/Netflix/vizceral 
while using HTML/ES5 Example with angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Please use this link https://github.com/Netflix/vizceral-example/. You can place vizceral and vizceral-example git source code under the same root directory. Run the vizceral-example as mentioned in the above link. It'll pick Vizceral code and display the results.